# Query in mysql database showing null values to zero and other values

Tags: mysql, select, join

i am being confused of this, i want to query or display clinic name and every clinic name i want to count all queue_id with it, something output like the output below: if the Clinic has null or there are no queue_id from it, then it will display 0. I am using mysql database.

```
(Clinic Name)     COUNT(QUEUE_ID's)
Clinic A        =   5
Clinic B        =   4
Clinic C        =   0
Clinic D        =   0
```

Here is my database tables :
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT
      tbl_clinics.clinic_name,COALESCE(COUNT(tbl_queue.queue_id),0) 
FROM tbl_clinics 
LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_queue
ON tbl_clinics.id=tbl_queue.clinic_id 
GROUP BY tbl_clinics.clinic_name;
```

Comment: Good, but back to front

Comment: i'll try this sir

Comment: hello sir.. i want to include those zero values .. the output comes only clinic name and its corresponding queue id count but doesn't include something like 
Clinic A = 0
Clinic B = 0

Answer (score -1):

Do you want to display clinic names right??
Select clinic_name from tbl_clinics